# MySQL Connection on Node.JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, ovh

I have a problem when I try to connect to a MySQL database hosted by OVH on NodeJS server. Here is the code :

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'my_ip',
  port     : '3306',
  user     : 'my_user',
  password : 'my_pass',
  connectTimeout : 10000
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected');
});
```

But I get :

```
error connecting: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Everytime, not matter what I do, like changing the timeout, remove the port or anything else. Any idea ? I'm running this on ArchLinux x86_64

Comment: What kind of hosting service is the database on? I'm asking because usually they don't allow remote connections to the database. Is the node server on the same machine or on a different one?

Comment: It's hosted on OVH and there's no problem to access it via PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer : OVH doesn't allow customers to use their MySQL Database out of their services which means that if you want to run code using MySQL OVH database, you have to run the code into a OVH server.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a timeout error.
Please try taking the port number out of the quote marks. Hopefully this will fix the issue!

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host     : 'my_ip',
     port     : 3306,
     user     : 'my_user',
     password : 'my_pass',
     connectTimeout : 10000
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it didn't change anything

Comment: Okay and can you connect to the remotely database using the same credentials in MySQLWorkbench for example?

Comment: It doesn't work, something might be wrong in the IP then ... Thanks for the help !

Comment: Yes, could be many things, is the database allowing remote connections or is it locked down? And are the credentials correct?